# NoMethodError in UsersController#update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I have done a seperate link to change password from devise but I am getting an error of:

> NoMethodError in UsersController#update undefined method `update' for
>   nil:NilClass

Can someone help me please!

**`users_controller.rb`**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    def show
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    def edit
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    def update
      if @user.update(user_params)
        redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.'
      else
        render :edit
      end
    end

    private
      def user_params
        params.require(:user).permit(:password, :password_confirmation)
      end


end
```

My **`edit.html.erb`** file in users

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>

 <div class="row">
   <label class="col-xs-4" for="password">New Password</label>
   <div class="col-xs-8">
   <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off", :placeholder => "New Password (leave blank if you don't want to change it)", :class => 'form-control' %>
   </div>
 </div></br></br>
 <div class="row">
   <label class="col-xs-4" for="password">Confirm Password</label>
   <div class="col-xs-8">
   <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off", :placeholder => "Enter password to confirm changes", :class => 'form-control' %>
   </div>
 </div></br></br>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :current_password %> <i>(we need your current password to confirm your changes)</i><br />
    <%= f.password_field :current_password %>
  </div></br></br>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Save", :class => "btn btn-primary" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
</div></div>
```

My error is:

> NoMethodError in UsersController#update undefined method `update' for
>   nil:NilClass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the user variable in the update action

```
def edit
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end

def update
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  if @user.update(user_params)
    redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.'
  else
    render :edit
  end
end
```